# Report viewer no muestra el reporte cuando corre en el servidor, pero si lo hace en modo local

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Buenas.Estoy trabajando con asp.net. Resulta que tengo un reporte que genero de esta manera:

```
private void MostrarReporte()
    {
        //reset
        rptViewerActaVolante.Reset();
        //dataSource
        int idMateria = Convert.ToInt32( Session["materia"]);
        DataTable dt = getData(idMateria);
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetActaVolante", dt);
        rptViewerActaVolante.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        //path
        rptViewerActaVolante.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        LocalReport localReport = rptViewerActaVolante.LocalReport;
        rptViewerActaVolante.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ActaVolante.rdlc";
        //refresh
        rptViewerActaVolante.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }

    private DataTable getData(int idMateria)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conexion.Cn))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spreporte_actaVolante", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idMateria", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idMateria;

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

En modo local funcionaba bien, pero cuando hice el deploy me da el siguiente error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   The report definition for report 'ActaVolante' has not been specified
>   No se pudo encontrar el archivo '\xxxx\public_html\ActaVolante.rdlc'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copia los archivos `*.rdlc` de tus reportes en el servidor. En la carpeta `public_html` para ser más exacto.

Para evitar eso, click sobre tu archivo `.rdlc`, en propiedades:

Copiar al directorio de salida: **Copiar siempre**

Comment: Buenísimo. No podía dar con el error, y no me di cuenta.

Comment: de nada bro, éxitos con el desarrollo :D